# Terraform code for GCP private cluster not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the terraform code for [GCP private](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-google-gke) cluster and it was working one month back, but today I am trying it and it's giving error now.

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Alias IP addresses are required for private cluster, please make sure you enable alias IPs when creating a cluster., badRequest

  on modules/gke-cluster/main.tf line 20, in resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster":
  20: resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
```

Am I missing somthing. Help will be appreciated

Comment: Please check here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/issues/133

Comment: Can you share how you set up your cluster?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-google-gke

Comment: What is the value you are using for this services_secondary_range_name.

Comment: @tarunkhosla, I let GCP pick the IPs within the range

Comment: So that means it is going as null , could you try with blank string , as the Google API  accepts servicesSecondaryRangeName as a string. Also you can try by assigning any value.

Comment: What's is yours config connector version?

Comment: @KoopaKiller, provider "google"  version = "~> 2.9.0"

Comment: @tarunkhosla, I tried by testing its blank string, but no luck and an error are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

To enable IP aliasing, you need to use the [`ip_allocation_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#ip_allocation_policy) property

The block can be left empty as all arguments inside are optional.